# numpy.ndarray is object is not callable in my case

Tags: python, numpy

I am a new user for python and I know there are a few discussions about this; however, I still cannot fix it.

I execute my homework as the following code:

[image]

How to fix the error in my code?  please advise, thanks!

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots, but as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ut variable is an array, 
try to change (line 69)

```
u = lambda t,x : ut(t)
```

to

```
u = lambda t,x : ut[t]
```

Comment: And probably also line 70 to `u = lambda t,x : ux[x]`.